# Dynamically Create a Foreign Key for Relationship Classes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, relationship-class

May be a relativity novice question but my research has turned up no direct answer.

I have a feature class of land owner parcels that I would like to preserve its schema. I would like to add fields that users could edit to determine various information about the parcel. My thought was to create a relationship class with a stand alone table that would contain the added fields. It would maintain 1:1 cardinality.

Here's the question.. Is there a way to configure this so that the foreign key is dynamically created from the origin table? Such that if a new parcel is added a new row in the table is created simultaneously?

Comment: I've never tried it so this may be a red herring but it sounds like a "composite" relationship you want to create?

Comment: I believe you are correct and have experimented a bit. Have not yet been able to produce the desired results.